Question regarding cuberoots of integral multiples of i
I decided to find the number $z$ such that
$$z^3 = 8i$$
And i wanted to do this in a geometric manner, first i decided to simply down and find
$$z^3 = i$$
One value for $z$ is obviously the point on the unit circle in the argand plane which is at an angle of $30^\circ$ from the x-axis in the first quadrant.
The coordinates of such a point are
$$(\cos(30^\circ) + i(\sin(30^\circ)))$$
Therefore one solution to the problem $z^3 = \iota$ is,
$$z = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} + \frac{i}{2}$$
I tried extending this solution to the case where $z^3 = 8i$
To do this i decided to multiply the $z$ i obtained when $z^3 = i$ by 8, as this would amount to scaling up that unit circle by a factor of 8.
Doing this the answer seems to be
$$4\sqrt{3} + 4i$$
However this does not seem to be the right answer, could anyone please point me in the right direction and point out the mistake i am making, any help would be appreciated!.

When cubing, the factor $8$ turns into $8^3$. You should instead scale by $\sqrt[3]{8}=2$.

What's your main motive???
To do in the most simplest way possible
$$z^3=8i \implies z^3+(2i)^3=0 $$
$$\implies (z+2i)(z^2-2zi-4)=0 $$
So either $z=-2i$, or by the quadratic formula,
$z=\frac{2i±\sqrt{-4+16}}{2}=i±\sqrt 3$
To do it geometrically
Let $z=Re^{ix},|z|=R,0≤x≤2π$
$$z^3=R^3e^{3ix}=8e^{(4n+1)\frac{π}{2}i},n=0,1,2$$
Hence by direct comparison,
$$R^3=8 \implies R=2 \ \text{and} \ x=\frac{π}{6},\frac{5π}{6},\frac{3π}{2}$$.
Hence you get
$$z=\sqrt 3 +i, -\sqrt 3 +i, -2i $$ as intended

If you write $z^{3}=8i$ as $z^{3}=(-2i)^{3}$ (since $i^3=-i$) you will see that the scale is by factor 2.
So the point you are looking at is $(2\cos{\frac{\pi}{6}},2\sin{\frac{\pi}{6}})$ and the complex number itself is $z=\sqrt{3}+i$
You can use De Moivre's formula to solve problems such as this:
If $z=r\cos{\theta}+i\sin{\theta}$ then $z^n=r^n\cos{n\theta}+i\sin{n\theta}$.
This will give you the three cube roots of $8i$:
$z_1=2(\cos{\frac{\pi}{6}}+i\sin{\frac{\pi}{6}})=\sqrt{3}+i$
$z_2=2(\cos({\frac{\pi}{6}+\frac{2\pi}{3}})+i\sin({\frac{\pi}{6}}+\frac{2\pi}{3}))=0-2i=-2i$
$z_3=2(\cos({\frac{\pi}{6}-\frac{2\pi}{3}})+i\sin({\frac{\pi}{6}}-\frac{2\pi}{3}))=\sqrt{3}-i$

I think you made a little mistake at the top. $(2i)^3=-8i$ not $8i$.

Ah yes, corrected now, with explanation. Thanks.
